# Esconder elemento se o mesmo está vazio

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tenho uma `div` que é utilizada para apresentar alertas ao utilizador:

```html
<div id="page-alerts" style="margin:25px 0;"></div>
```

## Problema

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/B2d5F/)

Por questões de formatação, a mesma contém margens em cima e em baixo, causando um *espaço em branco* igual ao valor das margens, quando se encontra vazia, o que quebra o layout.

[image: Captura de Tela com indicação do problema]

## Pergunta

Como esconder a `div` quando a mesma está vazia (sem alertas...) ?

Comment: Coloca 
<div id="page-alerts" style="margin:25px 0; display:none"></div> 

e quando for emitir o alerta tira o "display:none"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Você pode usar o pseudo-seletor [`:empty`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp) no seu CSS para tratar de elementos sem filhos (texto ou sub-elementos)

```css
#page-alerts {
     margin:25px 0;
}

#page-alerts:empty {
     margin: 0;
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/B2d5F/2/) Esse seletor funciona em todos os browsers, exceto IE8 ou anterior. No exemplo acima atribuí `margin` como `0`, mas você poderia usar por exemplo `display: none` se quiser esconder o elemento em absoluto.

Nota: essa regra funcionou bem no seu fiddle porque você usou CSS para atribuir o estilo; se você atribuir o estilo *inline* (como no código da sua pergunta)  então creio que ele terá precedência sobre as regras do CSS. Nesse caso, somente usando JavaScript para resolver. [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/B2d5F/5/):

```javascript
$("#page-alerts")
    .toggle(!$("#page-alerts").is(":empty"))
    .bind("propertychange DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
        $(this).toggle(!$(this).is(":empty"));
    });
```

(Fonte do código para ouvir por modificações na `div`: [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9488771/520779) no SOEN; não há menção quanto a quais browsers suportam o evento `DOMSubtreeModified`, mas [essa outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19869547/520779) diz que ele pode ser substituído por `propertychange` no IE)

Comment: Ótimo exemplo @mgibsonbr, não sabia desse seletor. Acredito que ficar melhor da forma que você  fez, do que colocar com 
"display:none"

Answer (score 0):

Coloque a div como padrão

```
display:none
```

Depois quando for preencher a div com o conteúdo coloque o

```
display:block
```

Caso você utilize Jquery

```
$(elemnto).show()
$(elemnto).hide()
```